# Alguien me puede explicar este algoritmo?

Tags: java, netbeans, estructuras-de-datos

es un ejemplo de un algoritmo de ordenamiento por insercion, pero no consigo llevar a palabras lo que hace:

````
int actual;
for (i = 1; i < unaLista.length; i++) {
actual = unaLista[i];
for (j = i; j > 0 && unaLista [j - 1] > actual; j--) {
unaLista [j] = unaLista [j - 1];
}
unaLista [j] = actual;
}
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

como vas? Muy buen día!!

He encontrado algunos errores, por favor revisa y cuéntame si ya se ajusta a lo que necesitas:

```
        import java.util.*;

        public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

// Se definen variables y arrays
        int actual;
        int unaLista[];
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

//Se inicia bucle for para recorrer cada dato del array "unaLista"
for (i = 1; i < unaLista; i++) {
//Se insertan los valores, menores que el tamaño del array, en el array "Actual"
actual = unaLista[i];
//Se recorre nuevamente el array "unaLista", pero de forma invertida
for (j = i; j > 0 && unaLista [j - 1] > actual; j--) {
//Se organizan los valores del array
unaLista [j] = unaLista [j - 1];
}
//Se asigna el nombre de la variable "actual" al resultado del array ya tratado
unaLista [j] = actual;
}
        System.out.println("XXXXXXXX");
}
}
```

**NOTA**: Al correr el código tal cual como esta, se genera un error porque el array unaLista no se ha inicializado, estimo que dependiendo de la necesidad del codigo, lo inicializas y listo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, es un ejercicio de una clase de algoritmos de la universidad, gracias a unos cuantos videos y a tu explicación lo entiendo más